# How do I apply a scale to a d3 v4.0 `brush`?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

In [`d3 3.x`](https://github.com/d3/d3-3.x-api-reference/blob/master/SVG-Controls.md), I would typically define and set up a brush with code like this:

```
let brushScale = d3.scaleLinear()
    .clamp(true)
    .domain([0, 100])
    .range([height, 0]);

let brush = d3.brush()
    .brushY(brushScale)
    .extent([0, 10]);
```

In [`d3 4.x`](https://github.com/d3/d3-brush), I don't see a corresponding function for associating a scale to the brush. Without a scale, I don't understand how I specify the overall range of the brush.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The meaning of `extent` has changed from v3 to v4.

[`extent` in v3](https://github.com/d3/d3-3.x-api-reference/blob/master/SVG-Controls.md#brush_extent) meant the brushed area, i.e. the selection range within the overall area circumscribed by the brush.

[`extent` in v4](https://github.com/d3/d3-brush#brush_extent) now refers to the overall area circumscribed by the brush, while the [`selection`](https://github.com/d3/d3-brush#brushSelection) is the selected area, what was previously referred to as `extent`. (Note that the selection can be accessed via `d3.brushSelection`, but is more commonly accessed as `d3.event.selection` in a brush event handler.

Also, in d3.v4, scales are no longer associated directly with brushes; instead, a brush operates only over a pixel area. Scales must be applied on the way in (on brush setup) and on the way out (to values returned by brush event handlers). So what was previously, in d3.v3:

```
let brush = d3.brush()
    .brushY(brushScale)
    .extent([0, 10]);
```

in d3.v4 becomes something like:

```
let brush = d3.brushY()
    .extent([[0, brushScale.range()[0]], [sliderWidth, brushScale.range()[1]]]);
let brushSel = svg.append('g').call(brush);
brush.move(brushSel, [sliderScale(0), sliderScale(10)]);
```

Note that instead of setting the selected area with `extent` (v3), we `move()` (v4) the selected area to a scaled pixel range.

Comment: Thanks for articulating some of these important changes.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of this:

```
let brush = d3.brush()
    .brushY(brushScale)
    .extent([0, 10]);
```

do this since you want a Y dimension brush:

```
let brush = d3.brushY()
    .extent([0, 10]);
```