# d3.js v4 brushY - can't change overlay width

Tags: css, d3.js, brush, parallel-coordinates

I've been trying to convert [this](https://bl.ocks.org/jasondavies/1341281#cars.csv) project with parallel coordinates from d3 V3 to V4. The problem encountered is when I try to apply brushing in the Y-axis for each dimension.

I fail to change the width of the overlay that is applied when brushing. It always has the width of 1000 units. It happens as soon as I implement brushing.

This is the code I have so far:

```js
// main.js
var margin = { top: 30, right: 10, bottom: 10, left: 40 },
    width = 1000 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

// The first element in domain will be mapped to the first point, the second domain value to the second point, and so on.
var x = d3.scalePoint()
    .range([0, width])

var y = {}; // Store linear scales for each dimension here!

var line = d3.line();     // https://github.com/d3/d3-shape#line
var axis = d3.axisLeft();
var background;
var foreground;

var dragging = {};
var dimensions = {};

// Create the main svg
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");


d3.csv("cars.csv", function (error, cars) {
    if (error) throw error;

    //// ==== Set Dimensions START ==== ////
    // d3.keys will get the field "names": { cylinders: 8 } cylinders is the key in this case. All the keys will be recieved!
    // For each car variable! d is the variable
    dimensions = d3.keys(cars[0]).filter(function (d) {
        if (d === "name") return false; // Exclude the dimension "name"
        return true;
    });
    // Set the x-axis domain to the dimensions
    x.domain(dimensions);

    // Create a linear y scale for each dimension.
    dimensions.forEach(function (d) {
        y[d] = d3.scaleLinear()
            .domain(d3.extent(cars, function (data) {
                // Return each cars value for specfied dimension d.
                return +data[d];
            }))
            .range([height, 0]);
    })
    //// ==== Set Dimensions END ==== ////

    //// ==== Draw Lines START ==== ////
    background = svg.append("g")
            .attr("class", "background")
            .selectAll("path")
            .data(cars).enter()
        .append("path")
            .attr("d", path)
    foreground = svg.append("g")
            .attr("class", "foreground")
            .selectAll("path")
            .data(cars).enter()
        .append("path")
            .attr("d", path)
    //// ==== Draw Lines END ==== ////

    //// ==== Draw Axis START ==== ////
    var g = svg.selectAll(".dimension")
            .data(dimensions).enter() // g's data is the dimensions
        .append("g")
            .attr("class", "dimension")
            // Give the axis it's propper x pos
            .attr("transform", function(d) {return "translate("+x(d)+ ")"; });
    g.append("g") // The Axis
        .attr("class", "axis")
        .each(function(d) { d3.select(this).call(axis.scale(y[d])); });
    g.append("text") // Axis Label
        .attr("class", "title")
        .style("text-anchor", "middle")
        .attr("y", -10)
        .attr("font-size", 15)
        .text(function(d) { return d; });
    //// ==== Draw Axis END ==== ////

    //// ==== Axis dragging START ==== ////
    g.call(d3.drag()
        .on("start", function(d) {
            dragging[d] = x(d);
            background.attr("visibility", "hidden");
        })
        .on("drag", function(d) {
            // Make sure the dragging is within the range.
            dragging[d] = Math.min(width, Math.max(0, d3.event.x));
            foreground.attr("d", path) // Redraw the lines when draging an axis
            dimensions.sort(function(a,b) {return xPosition(a) - xPosition(b)});
            // Set the domain to the new order of the dimension
            x.domain(dimensions);
            // Translate the axis to mouse position
            g.attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate("+ xPosition(d) +")"; 
        })
    })
    .on("end", function(d) {
        delete dragging[d];
        d3.select(this)
                .transition().duration(200)
                .attr("transform", "translate("+x(d)+")");
        foreground
                .transition().duration(200)
                .attr("d", path)
        background
                .attr("d", path)
                .transition().delay(200).duration(0)
                .attr("visibility", null);
    }));
    //// ==== Axis dragging END ==== ////

    //// ==== Brushing START ==== ////
    g.append("g")
        .attr("class", "brush")
        .each(function(d){
            d3.select(this).call(d3.brushY()
                .on("start", function(){ d3.event.sourceEvent.stopPropagation(); })
                .on("brush", function(d, i){ console.log(d) }))
        })
        .selectAll("rect") 
        .attr("width", 20)  // This part doesn't do anything!
    //// ==== Brushing END ==== ////
});

function xPosition(d) {
  var v = dragging[d]; // This array holds the temporary positions when dragging. 
    if(v == null) return x(d);
    return v;
}

function path(data) {
    return line(dimensions.map(function(dim){
        return [xPosition(dim), y[dim](data[dim])]
    }))
}
```

Here is a screenshot of the error, if it is to any help. In it, I've brushed the leftmost dimension and it stretches all the way to the right.

The same thing happens when I try to brush any other dimension, except that the overlay starts at that specific dimension and then stretches all the way to the right.

[image: Screenshot of error]

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, it works if I apply the proper width at .on("start") and .on("brush").
This feels like a hack though, and I fail to see why the previous solution works in V3 and not in V4.

```
//// ==== Brushing START ==== ////
g.append("g")
        .attr("class", "brush")
        .each(function(d){
            d3.select(this).call(d3.brushY()
                .on("start", function(){ 
                    d3.event.sourceEvent.stopPropagation(); 
                    g.selectAll("rect") 
                        .attr("width", 20)
                        .attr("x", -10)
                })
                .on("brush", function(d, i){ 
                    console.log(d) 
                    g.selectAll("rect") 
                        .attr("width", 20)
                        .attr("x", -10)
                }))
        })
//// ==== Brushing END ==== ////
```

Answer (score 0):

See this post [How do I apply a scale to a d3 v4.0 brush?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38712187/9994868)

I made each brush for multiple dimensions in a parallel coordinates plot like so:

```
dim.brush = d3.brushY()
    .extent([[dim.xPos - 10, this.margins.top], [dim.xPos + 10, this.height - this.margins.top]]);
```